# Python library issue

Tags: python, easy-install

I have a very peculiar issue with Python library. I downloaded the a python library source, changed some code and used `python setup.py install` to install the library.
The original library was already installed with `easy_install`. Later on I further changed some source code and called the command `python setup.py install` again. When I use the library in code, I randomly get different versions of the library being called. I am not able to fully uninstall the library too, even though by both `easy_install -m` and `pip` both say uninstall successful, the library persists.

The environment is Ubuntu 11.04

Edit: When I call the same function from Python commandLine the latest build is called, but when I call `python myfile.py` which uses the library it calls an older build.

Comment: @GWW I am running it on Amazon server. Cannot afford a reboot

Comment: When you say random, do you really mean random? i.e. can you run the same program multiple times in the exact same way and get different versions of the library used? Anyway, to find out where the library is being loaded from you can print the value of `library.__file__` and this should give you the directory the library is loaded from if you want to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An installer typically loads a third-party library code in the `site-packages` directory.  You can go to that directory and delete the library (that will include new and old versions).  Then you can do a fresh install (using setup.py on your edited source).

If the library is somewhere else on the path, you can find it with:

```
>>> import somelib
>>> print somelib.__file__
```

Comment: Used somelib.__file__ to recursely to find different every version of the library installed. Deleted each of them and used `python setup.py install` again.

Comment: nice, or inspect.getabsfile(somelib)